# Paramiko - Copying most recently modified directory

Tags: python

I need to write some code that connects to a remote server and given the path of a directory, copies the most recently modified directory. Ideally I would copy only the contents which are `.zip` files of the most recently modified directory but the entire directory wouldn't be a problem.

I have had a go with Paramiko and read some other questions but nothing seems to quite fit what I'm looking for. I've only got as far as copying a specific file using Paramiko.

```
import paramiko

hostname = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
password = 'password'
username = 'username'
port = 22

localpath_01=r'C:\Users\Dean\Documents\Work\Files from server\File_01'

remotepath_01='/home/dean/testdir/test_file.txt'


t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
t.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
sftp.get(remotepath_01, localpath_01)
```

I would rather not have my code executing commands on the remote machine.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sftp.listdir_attr` to first look for directories by checking `st_mode` with `stat`, and comparing `st_mtime` to get the last one modified. Once you have the directory, call `sftp.listdir_attr` again to look at its contents and `get` only files that end with `'.zip'`:

```
import paramiko
import stat

hostname = '***.***.***.***'
password = 'password'
username = 'username'
port = 22

local_path = r'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\testdir\\'

remote_path = r'testdir'

t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
t.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)

latest_time = -1
latest = None
for file_attr in sftp.listdir_attr(path=remote_path):
    if stat.S_ISDIR(file_attr.st_mode) and file_attr.st_mtime > latest_time:
        latest_time = file_attr.st_mtime
        latest = file_attr.filename

for file_attr in sftp.listdir_attr(path=f'{remote_path}/{latest}'):
    if file_attr.filename.endswith('.zip'):
        sftp.get(
            f'{remote_path}/{latest}/{file_attr.filename}',
            f'{local_path}{file_attr.filename}'
        )
```

Side note: I'm concatenating strings to build the remote and local paths. I would look into using something like `pathlib.Path` instead, specially if you're concerned about OS compatibility.

Comment: Perfect. Works just as I'd like after tweaking the paths. Thank you